# Eslint marks variable as unused when destruct array to delete item

Tags: javascript, eslint, destructuring

I have the following function in Javascript.

```
remove(item) {
    [item, ...this.list] = this.list
}
```

The code deletes one item from a list, and that works just fine.

The problem is that eslint is marking `item` as unused variable.

I know that I could suppress this error at the line level, or suppress `no-unused-vars` all together. But I want to know if there is a more elegant way around it.

After all, the variable *is* used, why does eslint reporting that error?

Comment: it's not being used, you could remove `(item)` and it wouldn't affect the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After all, the variable is used

It's not; you never reference `item` again, so it's correctly detected as unused.

You need to *completely omit* the leading item before the comma:

```
remove(item) {
    [, ...this.list] = this.list
}
```

But this looks odd. Some might consider instead:

```
remove(item) {
    this.list = this.list.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: OK thanks. Indeed my code didn't really do what I wanted. I wanted to delete the item `item` from the list. In stead it always deleted the first item. So I need to fix the code (eslint was trying to tell me something I didn't want to hear).